# Find the closest coordinate among several coordinates

Tags: c#, python, math, coordinates, formula

For example I have a `6` coordinates and names of `5` objects and my own location.

```
Stadium - 41.56569, 60.60677
Restoraunt - 41.561865, 60.602895
House - 41.566474, 60.605544
FishHouse - 41.55561, 60.63101
Cafe - 41.564171, 60.604020
```

My own location is `41.565550, 60.607537`.

The closest objects to me is Stadium i.e `41.56569, 60.60677`.

Help me calculate this value using some formula and `Python` or `C#` methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could add the building locations to a KD-tree and do nearest neighbor search

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a real question.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: EJoshuas, be gone plz. its really helpfull for minor users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `min` function like this:

```
import math

def nearest_location(locations, my_location):
    return min(enumerate(locations), key=lambda (_, (x, y)): math.hypot(x - my_location[0], y - my_location[1]))

locations = [(41.56569, 60.60677), (41.561865, 60.602895), (41.566474, 60.605544), (41.55561, 60.63101), (41.564171, 60.604020)]
my_location = (41.565550, 60.607537)

print(nearest_location(locations, my_location))
```

This prints `(0, (41.56569, 60.60677))` (the index of the location, and its coordinates).

If you are going to run this piece of code several times, a spatial data structure such as a quad-tree or a KD-tree might make more sense.

Comment: Thank you! How can i use this code on Python 3? I getting error message **"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"**  where  `"(_, (x, y))"`

Comment: I started writing a python on a python two days ago and ask not to scold me for it... I realize i need field def something like this `def func (_xy):`can u help me?

Comment: @InsendioFX I edited the answer, it defines a function and it has parenthesis around the `print` now

Comment: Thank you, you're the best!

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example of what it looks like to get u started.

```
{
private class Location
{
    float x;
    float y;
}

private List<Location> locationlist = new List<Location>();
private Location mylocation = new Location();

void findclose()
{
    int closestloc = 0;
    List<float> distances = new List<float>();
    int counter = 0;
    foreach(Location el in locationlist)
    {
        float distance =(x2−x1)2 + (y2−y1)2;
        distances.Add(distance);
    }
    float tempfloat = distances[0];
    foreach (float el in distances)
    {
        if (el < tempfloat)
        {
            tempfloat = el;
            closestloc=counter;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}

}
```